# transpose a particular row into column

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a query generated table of form

```
id  year  count
1   2014    4
2   2014    5
3   2014    6
1   2015    2
4   2014    6
2   2015    3
3   2015    4
4   2015    8
```

and I want to make it to the form:

```
id  2014 2015
1    4    2
2    5    3
3    6    4
4    6    8
```

I am using amazon redshift, which is postgres. The pivot and unpivot functions are not working, and I am unable to use crosstab function. Any help would be very useful. Thanks

Comment: When you say isnt working sound something like you should discuss with amazon customer support, isnt? What have you try and what error you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can always build a table like that using conditionals count with a group by

```
SELECT ID, 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN Year = 2014 THEN 1 END) as 2014,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN Year = 2015 THEN 1 END) as 2015
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
```